# What's the most efficient way to write a single record to an MS SQL 2008 Server using .NET?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, optimization

I'm writing a command-line tool (to run on Windows 7 boxes) that inserts a single record into a table and then exits.  I'm using C# (.NET 4.5) and SQL Server 2008.

The record of data contains a large (up to 6000 bytes) string, a time-stamp and an auto-incrementing integer ID primary key.  There are no foreign keys attached to the table.

Also, since this is the most common usage scenario for this database I'd like to optimise for it.  Are there any tricks with how I set up the database that will help keep individual insert times low?

[EDIT]
The code I'm currently using...

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
con.Open();
SqlTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [msglog](message,project,username,computername,updated_at) VALUES (@m,@p,@u,@c,@i,@t)", con, trans);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@u", Username);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", Computername);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m", msg);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", ProjectName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t", DateTime.Now);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
trans.Commit();
```

Comment: Added some code.  I'm wondering whether it would be faster to just write an SQL command as a string and execute it.  From a VS2012 Analyze pass it seems to be doing an awful lot of parsing, building and 'setting up of RPC parameters'.

Comment: Is your concern the amount of time the client takes to initiate the command, or the amount of time that SQL Server takes to complete the command, or both?

Comment: @Michael I haven't distinguished one from the other yet.  I'm looking at it from the client's perspective but it's the addition of the two times you mention that I want to reduce by whatever means are reasonable.  The last time I needed to do this level of SQL optimisation was when I was writing C some 10 years ago and back then I could see more clearly where it was spending its time.

Comment: How many inserts are you expecting per hour/minute/second/whatever?

Comment: @Ben What do you mean by "just write an SQL command as a string and execute it".  If you mean concatenate the parameters into a string instead of using parameters, don't do it!

Comment: I'm not _completely_ sure.  Probably around 10000 per hour.

Comment: @cadrell0 Ah, you're worried about SQL injection and the like yeah?  This is an internal app for my company so while I'd _rather_ avoid the risk I'd be willing to trade off some performance for safety. :)

Comment: @Ben using the parameterized query will allow SQL to recognize that and cache the execution plan.  Not using the parameterized query will force it to calculate a new one each time.  At least that's how it works on SELECTs.

Comment: If you're looking at the total time including starting an application just to run this single select, then you may well find that an unmanaged application is dramatically quicker - there's a significant overhead to starting managed applications.   Have you tried running the insert using the command-line SQL tool provided with MSQL and comparing performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code example, I suspect that most of the time is spent establishing a connection to SQL Server.  I would recommend:

- Attempt to reuse connections / a single instance of your application.  Your question suggests that the application opens, inserts a record, and then exits.  This requires constantly re-establishing a new connection for a single statement, not to mention overhead in launching the application itself.
- Remove your transaction (it's not needed for a single statement).
- Don't bother trying to build a single string for your statement.  You should use parameters, and it will likely be faster to use parameters.  SQL Server is more likely to cache the execution plan for identical queries (with changing parameter values).
- Make your table inserts fast (RedFilter has some great suggestions here).  I'd add that you would ideally cluster your table by an incrementing key, so that inserts are always at one end of the table.

There may be other micro-optimizations, but really addressing my first concern above would give you the most significant speedup.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't keep the application open without introducing significant complexity into my users' workflow.  I'll try removing the transaction control. I have only one index on the table (the primary key) and no triggers or computed columns.  I'm not familiar with clustering a table - I'll look into it.

Comment: By default, your primary key would be clustered.  If your primary key is the identity, then you would be all set.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to create a Windows service that connects to the database. Your application would send messages to the service which in turn would send the database update asynchronously. The other answers show good ways on the SQL side to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

As much as possible, eliminate these on the table you are inserting into:

- regular indexes
- full-text indexes
- triggers
- persisted computed columns

Also make sure there are no indexed views using this table.